# Reduce 4-SAT to 5-SAT

Tags: time-complexity, np-complete, np-hard, satisfiability, polynomial-time

given is a reduction from 4-SAT to 5-SAT.
How is it possible to describe such a function? 
I found some informations about reduction 3-SAT to 4-SAT [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/92888/to-prove-4-sat-cnf-is-np-complete), but it can't help me so much.

Comment: Can you define your version of $k$-SAT?

Comment: k-SAT = { F | F is a satisfiable Boolean formula in k-CNF }

Comment: What’s $k$-CNF for you?

Comment: Can you also explain what you don't understand in the linked answer? The reduction from 4-SAT to 5-SAT is essentially the same as the reduction from 3-SAT to 4-SAT.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I guess also that is the same way like 3SAT to 4SAT, but i was not sure! Thank you

Comment: To make @YuvalFilmus's question more specific, does "$k$-CNF" mean that each clause has _at most_ $k$ literals, or _exactly_ $k$ literals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a translation of the answer [how to prove 4-SAT CNF is NP-complete](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/92891/91753) to the current situation.

---

Suppose an instance of 4-SAT over variables $x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_m$ is given as a boolean formula $$f=c_1\land c_2\land \cdots\land c_m,$$ where $c_i$ is a disjunction that has exactly 4 literals for all $i$.

Introduce a new variable $s$. Suppose $c_i=w\lor x \lor y \lor z$ for some literal $w,x,y,z$. Let 
$$\begin{aligned}
c_{i+}&=w\lor x \lor y \lor z\lor s\\
c_{i-}&=w\lor x \lor y \lor z\lor \neg s.
\end{aligned}$$

- If $c_i$ can be satisfied by an assignment, then $c_{i+}\land c_{i-}$ is satisfied by the same assignment plus $s=0$ (or $s=1$).
- If $c_{i+}\land c_{i-}$ can be satisfied by an assignment, the same assignment without considering $s$ must satisfy $c_i$ since one of $s$ and $\neg s$ must be false.

Construct an instance of 5-SAT over variables $x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_m, s$, $$g=c_{1+}\land c_{1-}\land c_{2+}\land c_{2-}\land\cdots\land c_{m+}\land c_{m-}.$$

Because of the relation between $c_i$ and $c_{i+}\land c_{i-}$,

- If $f$ is satisfied by an assignment, then $g$ is satisfied by the same assignment plus $s=0$.
- Conversely, if $g$ is satisfied by an assignment, then $f$ is satisfied by the same assignment without considering $s$.

The above means the transformation from $f$ to $g$ is a reduction from 4-SAT to 5-SAT. It runs in polynomial time.

---

For simplicity of explanation, the above restricts $k$-SAT to CNF formulas with exactly $k$ literals without duplicates. Thanks to [a similar simple padding technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem#3-satisfiability), it is does not matter to the construction of reduction above whether we allow at most $k$ literals with or without duplicates when we define $k$-SAT.

Comment: very nice answer, Thank you very much!

Comment: @samTT, welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not specify exactly the two languages, let us suppose that 4-SAT is a CNF of this type: *(A ∨ B ∨ C ∨ D) ∧ (A¯ ∨ C¯ ∨ F ∨ S) ∧ (E ∨ G ∨ H¯ ∨ Q) ∧ ....* A way to reduce this instance of k-SAT into an instance of (k+1)-SAT is this: you can add inside every clause a further literal (for example Z) so the first clause will become **(A ∨ B ∨ C ∨ D ∨ Z)**, the second clause will become **(A¯ ∨ C¯ ∨ F ∨ S ∨ Z)**, the third clause will become **(E ∨ G ∨ H¯ ∨ Q ∨ Z)** and so on. It is easy to observe that by assigning the value 0 to the variable Z, you get an instance of 5-SAT which is verified if and only if the starting 4-SAT instance is verified.

Comment: You cannot assign a value to a variable &mdash; that's not how you specify a $k$-SAT instance.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus you are right, i meant that the adding of Z to every clause is trivial to the satisfabiality of the problem.